# getting error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException with my input data file

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I am researcher in biotechnology and I have to used java packages "BBTools" on windows 10 cmd  which is developed by https://jgi.doe.gov/data-and-tools/software-tools/bbtools/bb-tools-user-guide/installation-guide/. Accordingly, I have both program file including `.java` file and `.class` file along with specific data file. I have to processed data file with particular java package and tried so many times according to the user guide of packages mentioned.
But still I am getting error like `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` with my input data file. Please solve my problem. I have preinstalled Java latest version and also fixed the path in environment variable

Comment: Too little information. ClassNotFoundException happens when compiled code is executed trying to find a .class file (possibly in a .jar) which is not on the _"class path."_ The class path can be indicated inside a .jar in a MANIFEST.MF file, or on the command line as `java -cp <CLASSPATH>`. Change your title to include "bb.-tools"; maybe someone nows the software. Mention the class name that is not found.

Comment: Have you appended the needed dependencies to your classpath? ```ClassNotFoundException``` happened when you import some classes but didn't specify the ```jar``` files when executing.

Comment: What exact command are you using to run it?

Comment: thank you for yours copration

Comment: thank you for your cooperation. i am exactly using this; "C:\> java -cp (installation folder)\current jgi.AssemblyStats2 in=(installation folder)\resources\phix174_ill.ref.fa.gz".   And i have fixed the class path till Jgi folder in the environment variables and always getting same error like Error: Could not find or load main class in=resources\phix174_ill.ref.fa.gz
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: in=resources\phix174_ill.ref.fa.gz

Comment: That looks very wrong (there is no class or jar file visible), but using placeholders like "installation folder" [I *hope* that's a placeholder and you haven't written that *literally* ;) ] is going to make it tricky to assess

Comment: yes g00se, i have not written as literally and i follow the particular path. but several times i used like java -cp current\jgi\AssemblyStats2.Java in=resources\phix174_ill.ref.fa.gz and same result found